# Linq query to get all attributes of an item with a many to one relationship

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables/Entities

```
 public class Attribute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public bool Inactive { get; set; }      
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items{ get; set; }  
}

 public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Attribute> Attributes  { get; set; }      
}
```

I am trying to figure out the Linq query to retrieve all of the attribute names for an item ID where the attributes Inactive status is set to false. The attribute count could be 0 to 20.

Comment: What code have you tried to do this?

Comment: That's the problem everything I've tried in Linqpad doesn't get me anywhere close to pulling the data I want. I'll try to post my closest attempts.

Comment: This is the where I get stuck:  Items.Take (100).Where (s =>s.Attributes.Where (a =>a.Inactive.Equals(false)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should give you all of the attribute names for the item with the specified ID.

```
var selectedId = 1;  // The item ID you are looking for
var attrNames = items
    .Where(i => i.Id == selectedId)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Attributes)
    .Where(a => !a.Inactive)
    .Select(a => a.Name);
```